# SQL Error: ORA-00917

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I keep getting this error when attempting to submit a form to an Oracle DB saying I'm missing a comma, but I can't figure out where. Could it be that it's not referencing the code it shows below?

```
SQL Error: 917 - ORA-00917: missing comma
[query]

   INSERT INTO request_maps
    (
    request_cn
    ,new_map
    ,new_title
    ,new_legend
    ,new_lat
    ,new_long
    ,new_alpha
    ,TO_DATE(new_pubdate, 'MM-DD-YYYY')
    ,new_compiled
    ,new_pubby
    ,new_metadata
    ,new_disclaimers
    ,new_key
    ,new_matrix
    ,new_recmatrix
    ,new_township
    ,free_title
    ,free_legend
    ,free_desc
    ,free_insets
    ,free_key
    ,free_long
    ,free_lat
    ,free_township
    ,free_utm
    ,request_maps_type_cn
    ,created_by
    ) VALUES (
    :request_cn
    ,:new_map
    ,:new_title
    ,:new_legend
    ,:new_lat
    ,:new_long
    ,:new_alpha
    ,TO_DATE(:new_pubdate, 'MM-DD-YYYY')
    ,:new_compiled
    ,:new_pubby
    ,:new_metadata
    ,:new_disclaimers
    ,:new_key
    ,:new_matrix
    ,:new_recmatrix
    ,:new_township
    ,:free_title
    ,:free_legend
    ,:free_desc
    ,:free_insets
    ,:free_key
    ,:free_long
    ,:free_lat
    ,:free_township
    ,:free_utm
    ,:request_maps_type_cn
    ,:created_by
    )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
   INSERT INTO request_maps
    (reqest_cn
    ,new_map7
    ,new_title
    ,new_legend
    ,new_lat
    ,new_long
    ,new_alpha
    ,TO_DATE(new_pubdate, 'MM-DD-YYYY')          <-- change to new_pubdate
    ,new_compiled
```

You can't have an expression like that inside the field list...

Comment: i think he actually missed the VALUES key word